# OpenCV Face Recognition grayscale conversion error while training my classifier

Tags: python, opencv, face-recognition, cascade-classifier

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from skimage.io import imread_collection

dataset = r'C:\Users\JasonPC\Documents\CodeVault\Python\FaceRecognition\dataset\*.jpg' # path for images

List = imread_collection(dataset)
faces_list = np.array(List)

def classifier_trainer(faces_list):
    img_id = 0
    faces = []
    faceID = []
    for face in np.nditer(faces_list):
        gray_face = cv2.cvtColor(face, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # coverting color image to gray scale
        np_face = np.array(gray_face, 'uint8') # converting gray image into numpy array
        img_id += 1
        
        faces.append(np_face)
        faceID.append(img_id)
    faceID = np.array(faceID)
    classifier = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
    classifier.train(faces, faceID)
    classifier.write('Classifier.yml')

classifier_trainer(faces_list)
```

I'm trying to train a classifier to recognize my face. I'm stuck with this really huge error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/JasonPC/Documents/CodeVault/Python/FaceRecognition/trainer.py", line 26, in <module>
    classifier_trainer(faces_list)
  File "c:/Users/JasonPC/Documents/CodeVault/Python/FaceRecognition/trainer.py", line 15, in classifier_trainer   
    gray_face = cv2.cvtColor(face, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # 
coverting color image to gray scale
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.2.0) c:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.simd_helpers.hpp:92: error: (-2:Unspecified error) in function '__thiscall cv::impl::`anonymous-namespace'::CvtHelper<struct cv::impl::`anonymous namespace'::Set<3,4,-1>,struct cv::impl::A0xe227985e::Set<1,-1,-1>,struct cv::impl::A0xe227985e::Set<0,2,5>,2>::CvtHelper(const class cv::_InputArray &,const class cv::_OutputArray &,int)'
> Invalid number of channels in input image:
>     'VScn::contains(scn)'
> where
>     'scn' is 1
```

All I want my code to do is seek the images from the numpy array i.e `face_list` and convert it to grayscale and append it to a list called `faces`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in how you're iterating over your images. You're using `nditer` and in your case as it turns out it flattens the `n` dimensional array to say 1 dimensional and then iterates over all of it's elements. Think of it as a way of iterating over all elements of an `n` dimensional array without `n` nested loops. So here, the `face` variable in your loop is an integer, float or whatever numerical value and you're passing it to `cvtColor` and getting this error message.

If you want to iterate over the images I think, you can just iterate over them like this:

```py
for face in faces_list: 
    # your code goes here
```